Eclipse. Размер шрифта autocomplete. Как увеличить?
Подскажите пожалуйста, как как увеличить размер шрифта autocomplete?
При наборе например sysout само слово мелким шрифтом показано, а расшифровка нормальным.
Уже все настройки в шрифтах на 14 размер выкрутил а никак не помогает...

